# rich:dataTable doesn´t work with rich:scrolldata

Tags: richfaces

I have this code

```
    <f:view>
        <a4j:keepAlive beanName="datosCtrlBean" ajaxOnly="true"/>
        <h:form>
            <rich:dataTable   width="300" id="carList" rows="10" columnClasses="col"
                            value="#{datosCtrlBean.datos}" var="category"  >

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Make" />
                        </h:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category}" />
                </h:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">

                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>
            <rich:datascroller align="left" for="carList" id="sc2" />
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
```

datascroller working fine but the list of dataTable doesn´t refresh, but if I change by h:dataTable work fine.

what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxOnly` attribute is a flag that declares whether the value of the bean should be available during a non-Ajax request. If ajaxOnly="true", a request scope bean will keep the same value during Ajax requests from the given page, but it will be re-created as a regular request scope bean when a non-Ajax request will send from this page.

I would recommend to you to remove `ajaxOnly="true"` from `a4j:keepAlive`

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion, I created a new project with NetBean pluggin of richfaces and it is working now with o without parameter, may be in the last project I had a incorrect configuration. but thanks again.  cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might also help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-suggestion-box-component/

Comment: Thaks for yuor help.
I thought that my configurations it was wrong, I set from scratch followed the steps from richFaces documentation, maybe I put more jars that I needed it, after several hours I used Netbean plugging for RichFaces and JSF and it´s working fine